# Problems installing jhipster: "bash: jhipster: command not found"

Tags: jhipster

Im trying to install jhipster my very first time and having already problems  with the setup :o
I was following the steps on the "Installing JHipster" page for "Local installation with Yarn" (using Angular) which was working fine but now continuing with "Creating an application" gives me an error when trying to execute jhipster:

> To generate your application, type:
>
> jhipster

It seems there is just no jhipster binary in my environment even with following the setup steps described in the docs before:

```
test@test ~/git/test $ yarn global add generator-jhipster
yarn global v1.3.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Installed "generator-jhipster@4.13.3" with binaries:
      - jhipster
Done in 1.53s.
test@test ~/git/test $ jhipster
bash: jhipster: command not found
```

Was using [this page](http://www.jhipster.tech/installation/) for installing the requirements and [this page](http://www.jhipster.tech/creating-an-app/) for creating the app (having gentoo linux installed). As i was never using yarn or yeoman before im not sure if im missing something here like using a prefix or another program executing "jhipster".

Comment: The log says it installed `jhipster`binary, it could be a problem of PATH. Which version of node `node -v` and how did you install it?  Running `yarn global bin` should tell you where yarn install binaries.

Comment: Just updated node to the most recent (was something with v6.x before). But the real reason was indeed that the yarn binary PATH wasn't added automaticly. So i added it according to yarn global bin output and now it works. Thx a lot @GaëlMarziou

Answer (score 2):

Problem was i didn't have the yarn bin path added to my users PATH. See the comments for more informations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have problems using Yarn globally, be sure to have $HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin in your path.